Problem with loading 'raster' package: Unable to load from library() function
I'm trying to load the 'raster' package into my R session.
I already have it downloaded, but I used the install.packages() anyways at the beginning of the session. It gives me this output:
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but is not currently installed. Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/NAME/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.4/raster_3.6-30.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3682866 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

package ‘raster’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpC88ZET\downloaded_packages
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address
Error in .External(list(name = "CppMethod__invoke_notvoid", address = <pointer: (nil)>,  : 
  NULL value passed as symbol address

I then try to use the library() function to call the raster package, and it returns this error code:
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘raster’:
 Functions found when exporting methods from the namespace ‘raster’ which are not S4 generic: ‘colSums’, ‘rowSums’

Then, when I try to use the raster() function, it returns an error code it could not find that function.
I've tried using update.packages() but that hasn't fixed it. I am running R version 4.4.2 and RStudio version 2024.9.1.394 if that could affect anything.
I do really need this package for its 'raster' function and haven't found a workaround to use another package, so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Rtools cannot be installed from within R. It is a system package. Please spend more time reviewing the documentation for the Windows version of R, especially the R-Win.faq.

First, install Rtools on your system after downloading it from here. Then, you can try install.packages('raster', dependencies=TRUE).

There is no need to install RTools. You only need that to install packages from source code that needs compilation, and there is no reason to do that here.
